# Ubuntu sometimes doesn't start up properly

Tags: graphics, startup, amd-ryzen

Here is my problem.

I have ubuntu on my computer.

When I turn on my laptop, it loads grub, then I select ubuntu and then...

Sometimes login screen appears, but sometimes it just dark screen with cursor pointer. (approximately 3/5 unsuccessful starts).

I bought this laptop about a half a year ago. And from then I was facing this type of issues every day.

My laptop has an AMD Ryzen 7 graphic card. Is it related to the problem?

Maybe, I should just change distro and graphic environment? I think gnome has some problems with AMD(or vice-versa).